# Double Direct Integration

Tags: python, integration, ode, differential-equations, boundary

I am trying to solve the set of coupled boundary value problems such that;

```
U'' +aB'+ b*(cosh(lambda z))^{-2}tanh(lambda*z) = 0,

B'' + c*U' = 0, 

T'' = (gamma^{-1} - 1)*(d*(U')^2 + e*(B')^2)
```

subject to the boundary conditions `U(+/- 1/2) = +/-U_0*tanh(lambda/2)`, `B(+/- 1/2) = 0 and T(-1/2) = 1`,  `T(1/2) = 4`. I have decomposed this set of equations into a set of first order differential equations, and used the derivative array such that `[U, U', B, B', T, T']`. But bvp solve is returning the error that I have a single Jacobian. When I remove the last two equations, I get a solution for `U` and `B` and that works fine. However, I am unsure why adding the other two equations results in this issue.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
alpha = 1E-7
zeta = 8E-3
C_k = 0.01 
sigma = 0.005
Q = 30
U_0 = 0.1
gamma = 5/3
theta = 3

def fun(x, y):

    return y[1], -2*U_0*Q**2*(1/np.cosh(Q*x))**2*np.tanh(Q*x)-((alpha)/(C_k*sigma))*y[3],  y[3],\
        -(1/(C_k*zeta))*y[1], y[4], (1/gamma - 1)*(sigma*(y[1])**2 + zeta*alpha*(y[3])**2)

def bc(ya, yb):

    return ya[0]+U_0*np.tanh(Q*0.5), yb[0]-U_0*np.tanh(Q*0.5), ya[2]-0, yb[2]-0, ya[4] - 1, yb[4] - 4

x = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 500)
y = np.zeros((6, x.size))


sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, x, y)
print(sol)
```

However, the error that I am getting is that 'setting an array with sequence'. The first function and boundary conditions solves two coupled equations, then I use these results to evaluate the equation I have given. I have tried writing all of my equations in one function, however this seems to be returning trivial solutions i.e an array full of zeros.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this

Comment: Thank you, I will post something on there

Comment: Try again with `y[5]` in the place of  `T'` instead of `y[4]`. Does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the expressions become larger it is often more helpful to keep the computations human readable instead of compact.

```py
def fun(x, y):
    U, dU, B, dB, T, dT = y;
    d2U = -2*U_0*Q**2*(1/np.cosh(Q*x))**2*np.tanh(Q*x)-((alpha)/(C_k*sigma))*dB;   
    d2B = -(1/(C_k*zeta))*dU;
    d2T = (1/gamma - 1)*(sigma*dU**2 + zeta*alpha*dB**2);
    return dU, d2U, dB, d2B, dT, d2T
```

This avoids missing an index error as there are no indices in this computation, all has names close to the original formulas.

Then the solution components (using initialization with only 5 points, resulting in a refinement with 65 points) plots as

[image]

Comment: This is very useful feedback. I tried your suggestion of y[5] going to y[4], and i do in-fact get solutions. I get my usual behaving solutions for U and B, however the solution for T is always linear no matter the parameters. This seems odd to me, because U and B seem to change dramatically. However, I do not see a mistake anywhere? I think T should be changing.

Comment: I am supposing that somehow T is coming out linear regardless, because the equation for T'' is direct integration, but between two boundaries.

Comment: It is worth adding here that when I plot x against T (which I assume is y[4]) I get a linear plot. However, when I plot x against T' (y[5]) I do not get a flat horizontal line (which I would expect for a straight line).

Comment: Thank you for uploading some plots. How are you plotting DT? I cannot obtain a flat line. I am plotting x against y[4] and x against y[5]. When I do that, x against y[4] indeed is a straight line like yours. However my graph for DT does not look like that.

Comment: If you got the same plot as the last component above, note the `+3` above the y-axis which tells you that the numbers at the ticks are offsets to `3.0000`, so the y-range is from 2.9996 to 3.0004, which is an almost straight constant line.

Comment: That first plot was in error, it was run with a python 2 kernel where gamma=5/3 evaluates to 1.

Comment: The constants in the T equation are so small that T'' is some 1E-2, so that the T curve has almost no curvature, giving you an almost straight line.